# How to program a Wcf service to accept xml data?

Tags: xml, wcf

I need to write a wcf service that accepts 3rd party applications to send a xml file to the wcf service.

An example of a xml file could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Name 1</Name>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Name 3</Name>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

How do I setup the wcf service to accept this collection of data?

Answer (score 4):

This would be one way, it allows you to HTTP POST a non-soap formatted, untyped request to the service at the address `http://<your-url>/<your-service-name>/ReceiveCustomers`

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "ReceiveCustomers", Method = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare] 
[XmlSerializerFormat]    
public void ReceiveCustomer(XElement customers)
{
 ....
}
```